# import the updated excel value to database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, excel

I have a large amount of data in a excel sheet which has about 2000 rows. I have imported the table in sql server with no error. 
I have to modify the excel now and update the same changes in the database also. 
I cant delete the table and import again since i have large amount of data and have extra columns added to it.

So Please help me how to update the new values along with the existing values. I use C#.Net.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Import into a temp table and then use the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to update your master table.

Comment: hi. i tried it. I am not able to update the changed values in merge statement.I can update only if any new values are added.

Comment: @Anoozz, did you use the ` WHEN MATCHED ` part?